# Vue : import export json with javascript contained

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a json look like below and I wish to import from different component, because this json contain `require` and `Math` etc. Unable to save into json file format

```js
let test = [
    {
      name:"A",
      imgSrc: require('@/assets/img/A.png'),
      range: Math.pow(10, 6),
      isShow: true
    },
    {
      name:"B",
      imgSrc: require('@/assets/img/B.png'),
      range: Math.pow(10, 2),
      isShow: false
    }
  ];
```

Comment: make this as a .js file then try to import

Answer (score 1):

Copy that declaration into a JavaScript file, and use the [`export` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export#using_named_exports) in front of it:

```js
// products.js
export let test = [/*...*/]
```

Then in another JavaScript file, you could use the [`import` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#import_a_single_export_from_a_module) to pull in the variable by name:

```js
// main.js
import { test } from './products'
```